# Seconds passed in the app don't correspond to real seconds elapsed

Tags: javascript, cordova, time

I'm making a game using cordova and I need to calculate the difference of time in seconds between the user quitting the app and the user re-opening it.
Here's my code to achieve this:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentTime = date.getTime();
var lastTime = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('lastTime'));
var timeDifference = Math.round((currentTime - lastTime)/1000 );
```

*lastTime* is equal to *date.getTime()* executed on user exit.

The problem is that *timeDifference* doesn't actually hold the seconds elapsed since the last exit, instead it holds a much greater value.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared the expect and actual values of currentTime, lastTime, and timeDifference it would help

Comment: I can't predict the times. If the user quits the app the time when he quitted is saved in milliseconds. When the user opens the app again, the difference between the time he quitted and the time he's opened the app is made. Dividing this result by 1000 should give the seconds that have elapsed since the user last exit. A real sample is: lastTime = 1442067696551; currentTime = 1442067707287; timeDifference = 11.

Comment: OK, so it shows 10.736 seconds between the application closing and then opening again. You said in the original problem that the values for timeDifference were much greater that you expected. What were you expecting? How long between closing and restarting the application? 11 seconds doesn't seem like a great amount of time.

Comment: The point is that I just closed and opened the app after like 1 or 2 seconds. Time difference shouldn't be 11 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the pause/resume event:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

// Handle the resume event
//
function onResume() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentTime = date.setTime();
    var lastTime = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('lastTime'));
    var timeDifference = Math.round((currentTime - lastTime)/1000 );
}

// Handle the pause event
//
function onPause() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentTime = date.getTime();
    window.localStorage.setItem('lastTime', currentTime);
}
```

See the cordova documentation for [more information about events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html).

Comment: This is useful when the app is put in the background but I'm talking about actually exiting the app.

Comment: Before the app the is closed, the pause event is triggered.